# Does StreetPass still work if a DS game is suspended/sleeping in a 3DS?

Tags: streetpass

I am playing Solatorobo: Red the Hunter (which is a DS title) on my 3DS, and I often just shut the 3DS while I am walking around (thus suspending the game).

It seems, however, that I never manage to pick people up via StreetPass while I have a DS game suspended in my 3DS.

Is this actually the case? Is there something about suspending a DS game that prevents StreetPass from working? Or have I just been unlucky?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No - StreetPass will not work if a (regular) DS title is suspended.

StreetPass will definitely occur if a 3DS title is suspended with the system on, closed, and transmitting wireless.  (I've had this happen with Ocarina of Time.)

StreetPass will also often work when the system is open and you're actively playing.  I've had this occur many many times when using StreetPass Mii Plaza (Plaza and Find Mii II), and even in Street Fighter IV 3D.

Comment: "Closed" doesn't seem to be necessary. I've gotten streetpassed with my 3DS open in StreetPass Mii Plaza and Kid Icarus: Uprising. In both cases I was in the StreetPass UI _for those games_, which may make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

Streetpass works that way with some 3DS games, but not with regular DS games.

Comment: Could you give more of an exact answer of StreetPass only works with selected 3DS titles, or just never with DS games in a 3DS or.. whatever the answer actually is?

Comment: I thought my answer was completely clear... not sure what you are looking for...

Comment: Sorry, I mean something like what Katiek did, Exact statements that can be read on their own with out having to go refer to the question. That way I do not have to try and figure out which 'that way' you may be referring to.

Comment: Oh ok sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Certain DS games have something similar to streetpass called tag mode. If a DS game with tag mode is inside your 3DS, streetpass will be disabled. If a DS game without tag mode is inserted, you will still be able to use streetpass with the game inside.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, indeed it works if you have a 3DS and it is suspended or on sleep mode

Comment: As an answer to "Does StreetPass still work if a **DS** game is suspended/sleeping in a 3DS?", this is not correct.  StreetPass will work when 3DS games are suspended, but not DS games.